# automl NaN in leaderboard performance

Tags: h2o

I am using H2O.AI h2o.automl function to perform a standard binary classification problem. I am  using the last package version published on CRAN. I ran the following code:

```
my_automl_model<-h2o.automl(x=predictorsList, y="Purchase", training_frame = train.h2o, validation_frame =  test.h2o, stopping_metric = "logloss", max_runtime_secs = 60*60*3).
```

being purchase a two levels factors ("N", "S") and the predictors' list is predictorsList.

The log of the fast call is the following:

```
                                   model_id auc logloss
1 GLM_grid_0_AutoML_20171012_150410_model_1 NaN     NaN
2 GLM_grid_0_AutoML_20171012_150410_model_0 NaN     NaN
3     DeepLearning_0_AutoML_20171012_145911 NaN     NaN
4  StackedEnsemble_0_AutoML_20171012_145911 NaN     NaN
5 GLM_grid_0_AutoML_20171012_145911_model_1 NaN     NaN
6 GLM_grid_0_AutoML_20171012_145911_model_0 NaN     NaN
```

I understand that the package ranks the model, but I wonder why no performance metrics is shown...

Also I would like to understand:
1. what XRT_xxx models represent?
2. if there is any way to specify n-folds cross validation.

Thanks in advance for the support

Comment: Can you reproduce this error on a public binary classification dataset, or can you share your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I'll address the two questions at the end for now and update my answer if you can provide a public dataset that replicates the NA in the leaderboard problem.

> 1. what XRT_xxx models represent?

XRT = A Random Forest that uses Extremely Randomized Trees (aka [ExtraTrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#ExtraTrees)).  This is achieved by setting `histogram_type = "Random"`.

> 2. if there is any way to specify n-folds cross validation.

Right now you can use the `fold_column` to specify custom folds, so you could can change the number of folds this way.  This should be a column of integers or factors that specify the fold, so the simplest way to create this is something like (R example):

```
# train should be your training_frame; we will use iris as an example
data("iris")
train <- as.h2o(iris)

# add a fold column that uses 10 folds
train[,"fold"] <- as.h2o(rep_len(1:10, nrow(train)))
```

Then set `fold_column = "fold"` in `h2o.automl()`.

In the next release, we will expose the `nfolds` argument directly to make this easier (follow progress on this task [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4882?filter=20700)).

Comment: Hi Erin, thanks for the initial insights... I will try to replicate the issue on a open db and then update comments.